# git merge does not keep links between files that are moved, renamed, and modified

Tags: git, merge

I need to work on a branch that will considerably changes the project. I import a php framework and I need to rename, move and modify existing files.
My problem is the maintainability of my branch  when I need to merge the Master on it (or any other branch).

An example : 
on master : dir1/toto.php
on my branche that file became : dir2/dir3/titi.php with modifications inside

If the master evolves and if I want to merge toto.php, Git will lost the link with my new path of the file (dir2/dir3/titi.php). So, a git merge will re-import dir1/toto.php and i need to manually do a local diff...loosing all the git advantages.

Have you any help ?
NB : I work with phpstorm, using git with the UI.

Thank for all

Guillaume

Comment: Git does not keep links between files that are moved or renamed. It tries to detect this operations when it needs to report them. It uses the similarities between the files to detect the renames and moves and it sometimes fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although git does not track file movement, it does attempt to recognize that a file moved during a merge.  It's not perfect, but it does a pretty good job and there are parameters you can tweak to try to convince it to "see" that the file moved.

If you want to give git the best chance to handle the merge correctly, then when you have to move a file and change its contents, break it up into two commits - one to move the file without changing it, and one to change it without moving it.  When a file disappears and exactly one identical file appears elsewhere, git is quite good at recognizing this as "file moved".